# CQRS/NES - Insight into how sample project works?

Tags: nservicebus, cqrs, neventstore

I have just had a look at NES which uses EventStore and NServiceBus for CQRS.

Up to now I had not even looked at NServiceBus.

The sample project provided for NES has an MVC client which interacts with NServiceBus which raises or publishes and event from the domain of the user...etc..

As you can tell I am a bit confused on what and who calls what, who does sends and who does the publishing and who is subscribing.

If any one could give me an intro of how the sample project works, that would be a good start into getting into NES and NSB?

Thanks

JD

Ps. The NES project looks amazing, just now need to build my theory to understand how it all works.

Comment: Download NSB, and take a look at the examples in there. They are really straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NES sample contains two main projects, the MVC website and the NServiceBus endpoint. The website sends commands to the endpoint and the endpoint publishes events.

To keep the NES sample as simple as possible the NServiceBus endpoint is also listening for its own events, handling them after they're published and in turn creating the Dtos. Typically another separate endpoint would be running that would handle the events instead.

Hope this helps a bit.